# DRAM in a FPGA - Image Sensor design

Tags: fpga, sdram, image-sensor, dram

I am designing the simplest form of a camera: an FPGA that interfaces an image sensor and sends the acquired data to the host device via USB 3.0. There is no processing on the FPGA, it is used for sensor control and data acquisition.

By studying various resources online, I observed that typically a DRAM is included in the design to store sequential frames as well as intermediate processing results. At first, my plan was to implement:

Image Sensor ==> FPGA ==> DRAM  (Acquisition)

DRAM==>FPGA==>USB Controller (Transfer to host)

Since no image processing is done, I was wondering if it is safe to omit the DRAM in the design for reducing design complexity. So, the pixel data will go directly from the FPGA to the USB Controller in every cycle, and implementing a small internal RAM as a very small pixel buffer in case there is a temporary stall from the USB controller.

Is that feasible or I will have many frame losses due to transfer bottlenecks?

Comment: What is your data rate from the sensor? How fast can the host process incoming data on the USB connection?

Comment: @Elliot Alderson The particular sensor I am working with right now has a maximum data rate 96 MP/s with a clock at 96 MHz but this is intended to be a general design pattern so later other sensors will be used. The host process data pretty fast (CUDA based ISP), but I assume this is not a problem since a frame will be given from the board upon request, so the host is ready to receive.

Comment: Perform Worst-case analysis, starting with calculating throughput requirements to properly size your buffer(s).  Think about: Is your sensor a serial or parallel interface?  if parallel, how many bits?  Are you pushing to the Host or notifying it to retrieve it?  How much inter-frame time is there?  What is max data rate on the USB interface?  You will have to be approx. "sizeOfPixels faster on USB" to keep up with the input, if the input is parallel and has a nominal inter-frame gap.  Think about interface latency, arbitration (if any), etc. and then apply the math on a timeline.

Comment: Stall on the USB, as you mentioned, is another WCA thing to consider.... if the aggregate stall time is longer than inter-frame gap it won't matter if you stored everything in a DRAM previously or not.  This is another place where the Host specs will come into your WCA timeline calculation... is it a dedicated USB link or not, priority, etc.

Comment: So you need at something like 800 Mb/s data transfer over USB? (Assuming 8 bit pixels.) How many pixels in an image..how long do you need to sustain that data rate to transfer one frame? It doesn't matter how fast the host can **process** the pixels, how fast can the host **transfer** data over USB?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Generally speaking, regardless of sensor, I am aiming at Full HD, 25 FPS, for preview (which translates to roughly 52 MB/s or 416 Mb/s) and the full resolution the sensor can provide for a snapshot. The sensor I am currently working with has a max resolution of 2592 x 1944 and can provide a maximum framerate of 14 FPS at that resolution (which translates to 75 MB/s or 605 Mb/s), and transfers data via parallel interface. The next target sensor has a max res 3096 x 2080 @ 30 FPS, using LVDS to communicate the data, so it's significantly higher than the previous one.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson The host device is a regular desktop/tablet as long as it has USB 3.0 support. The host is not a dedicated PC, the camera should be able to function properly in "any" relatively modern device. As long as how fast can the host transfer data, I assumed when asking the question that a relatively modern PC can achieve at least 800 Gb/s as a safe low limit, which is almost 1/5 of the maximum transfer rate USB 3.0 is supposed to achieve.

Comment: @CapnJJ Thanks for your answer, I will take everything you said into consideration. My current sensor has a parallel interface, while the next will have LVDS. It is not clear to me how the interface of the sensor affects the design concept, and I will be grateful if you could elaborate on that.

Comment: parallel vs serial only matters in as much as data throughput, it wasn't clear to me originally how big a pixel is, or how many pixels you were receiving per transfer and at what rate... it seems you have the numbers as you have stated in subsequent comments.  Start with Best-Case Analysis, (i.e. "straight through") and see if the timeline works out.  Then, backup from there in terms of any USB throttling, host processing time for a frame, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RAM has a buffer functionality. This way you can send data bursts instead of trying to synchronize your incoming and outgoing datastream. Depending on the protocol you might have some significant overhead so you want to have as much data as possible packed in a single frame. Using a RAM buffer you can check if data has been stored and then build your frame and the camera doesn't directly rely on a ready USB connection.
So technically you can omit the RAM but I'd at least implement a fifo-buffer (ringbuffer) in the FPGA.